# How can I make images small enough for profile settings?

Tags: windows-xp

I spend mega time uploading images into different profile pages, only to be told they are either too small or two large.

I find it some times helps to insert them into Word and making them smaller, but hoping there is an **easier way**. I tried playing around with pixels but nothing works--probably because I don't understand pixels?

1. I am adding link to my Google profile (if it works):

   [Google Profile][1]

   [1]: https://plus.google.com/u/0/110955750143915319743/posts. even this is cropped.
2. Another resizing problem is in my blog. I am embarrassed to post a link as I am working on dropdown tabs, that are functioning, but vertically centered. I seem to make mountains out of molehills and I see lots of mountains on the horizon. If you hover over my gadget, "What I Love About My Husband", you can see the images are of different sizes, aaaagh. Would it help if I created a Webflow blog. If so, can I import from my Blogger blog? Or am I way over my league on this forum.

Thanks for looking, Lucie "iweararedhat.blogspot.com"

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please clarify what profile pages you are talking about.

Comment: Which profile pages are you talking about? Which website?

Answer (score 1):

An easier way would be to use a good image editing program, e.g. [Irfan View](http://www.irfanview.com/)
All you need to do is to change the size of your picture: **Image** -> **Resize/Resample** ...

[image]

Comment: https://plus.google.com/u/0/110955750143915319743/posts